# mql4でMT4のインジケータZigZagの価格を利用してEAを作りたいです

Tags: mql4

MQL4でMT4のインジケータZigzagを使ってEAを作っています。
チャート図に描画されているZigZagの山と谷の価格と、MQL4でコードを書いて導き出した価格が違っています。
解決方法を教えて下さい。

```
double   zigzag = 0;       // ZigZagインディケータの値
   double   zig[5];           // 頂点を保存する一時変数
   int      zig_count = 0;    // 見つけた頂点の数
   int      i;

   // 1. ZigZagインディケータの頂点を5個探す（1本前の足～Max本前まで）
   for (i=0; i<=1000; i++)
   {
      // i番目の足のZigZagを計算
      zigzag = iCustom(NULL, 0, "ZigZag", 12, 5, 3, 0, i);

      // ZigZagの値が0かを判定し、0でなければ頂点とする
      if (zigzag == 0) continue;

      // 頂点を保存する
      zig[zig_count] = zigzag;
      zig_count++;

      // 5個頂点が見つかったら探索終了
      if (zig_count >= 5)
         break;
   }

Comment("zig[0]=",zig[0]+"\n"+"zig[1]=",zig[1]+"\n"+"zig[2]=",zig[2]+"\n"+"zig[3]=",zig[3]+"\n"+"zig[4]=",zig[4]);

描画されたZigZagの頂点は、
108.061
109.749
108.506
110.234
107.791
Commentでチャート図の左上に表示させた、ZigZagの頂点の価格
zig[0]=108.103
zig[1]=109.749
zig[2]=108.506
zig[3]=110.234
zig[4]=107.791
```

Comment: 英語版サイトの方にタグが作られていて記事も結構あるようなので、英語に翻訳してそちらで質問すると早いかもしれません。[mt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mt4), [metatrader4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metatrader4), [mql4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mql4)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。